# Groovy Scripting - Grape - No suitable driver found for H2

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to instantiate an in-memory db, i.e H2 using Grape, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting classloader issues.

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
        at java_sql_DriverManager$getConnection.call(Unknown Source)
        at main.run(main.gsh:48)
```

Here's my code

```
@Grapes([
        @Grab(group = 'com.h2database', module = 'h2', version = '1.4.192')
])
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test");
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, according to the [Grape documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-JDBCDrivers), one needs to additionally specify

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
```

to load JDBC drivers correctly.

After adding this, the errors go away.